# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'crm.email' doesn't exist (Connection: mysql, SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `email`

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

i was storing form data and got the error, "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'crm.email' doesn't exist (Connection: mysql, SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `email` where `email` = TEST@gmail.com)"

I send the form data to server, this is my code

```
<form action="{{route('CustomerCheckStore')}}" method="post">
                @csrf
                <div class="cusmrentryforminput">
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="*" required="">
                    <span>Name</span>
                    @error('name')
                        <p class="err">{{$message}}</p>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="cusmrentryforminput">
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="*" required="">
                    <span>Email</span>
                    @error('email')
                        <p class="err">{{$message}}</p>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="cusmrentryforminput">
                    <input type="phonenumber" name="phonenumber" placeholder="*" required="">
                    <span>Phonenumber</span>
                    @error('phonenumber')
                        <p class="err">{{$message}}</p>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="cusmrentryforminput">
                    <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="*" required="">
                    <span>Address</span>
                    @error('address')
                        <p class="err">{{$message}}</p>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="cusmrentryforminput">
                    <input type="text" name="zipcode" placeholder="*" required="">
                    <span>Zip Code</span>
                    @error('zipcode')
                        <p class="err">{{$message}}</p>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="cusmrentryforminput">
                    <input type="country" name="country" placeholder="*" required="">
                    <span>Country</span>
                    @error('country')
                        <p class="err">{{$message}}</p>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="cusmrentryforminput">
                    <input type="text" name="cardhodler" placeholder="Optional">
                    <span>Card Holder</span>
                </div>
                <div class="cusmrentryforminput">
                    <input type="text" name="cardnumber" placeholder="Optional">
                    <span>Card Number</span>
                </div>
                <div class="cusmrentryforminput">
                    <input type="number" name="cardexpire" placeholder="MM/YY">
                    <span>Expire Date</span>
                </div>
                <div class="cusmrentryforminput">
                    <input type="number" name="cvv" placeholder="Optional" min="3" max="3">
                    <span>CVV</span>
                </div>
                <div class="cusmrentryforminput">
                    <input type="Remarks" name="remarks" placeholder="*" required="">
                    <span>Remarks</span>
                    @error('remarks')
                        <p class="err">{{$message}}</p>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="cusmrentryforminput">
                    <input type="Submit">
                </div>
            </form>
```

and ther server code

```
public function CustomerDataStore(Request $req)
    {
        $validatdada = $req->validate([
            'name'=> 'required',
            'email'=> 'required|unique:email',
            'phonenumber'=> 'required',
            'address'=> 'required',
            'zipcode'=> 'required',
            'country'=> 'required',
            'remarks'=> 'required'
        ]);


        return view('CustomerEntry.successful');
    }
```

i created table name "customerdata" but when i try to store data through the controller and model("customerdata"), it gave me the error and continuously giving me the error even i deleted the table name "customerdata" and its model and also rollback the migration.

anyone know why i'm getting the error even i am not using the database just sending the data?

Comment: The error isn't coming from this code. Look in the logs in `storage/logs` to see if there's more information, but it's trying to access something about emails

Comment: yes this is the error is showing = "[2023-03-15 12:28:29] local.ERROR: syntax error, unexpected token ":", expecting "]" {"exception":"[object] (ParseError(code: 0): syntax error, unexpected token \":\", expecting \"]\" at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\CRM\\routes\\web.php:20)"

Comment: That's from the 15th, not from today

Comment: [2023-03-30 12:18:54] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'crm.email' doesn't exist (Connection: mysql, SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `email` where `email` = TEST@gmail.com) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'crm.email' doesn't exist (Connection: mysql, SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `email` where `email` = TEST@gmail.com) at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\CRM\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:760)
[stacktrace]

Comment: Well, that doesn't help, since it doesn't give a full trace log. Look for middleware or another controller that's trying to look up the email

Comment: thanks, i got the exact error and now its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the validation arrives to the email it looks in db for an email table, and it can't find it.

wha you are probably trying to do is to have a unique email but you have to tell laravel the correct table name to look for.

es:
'email' => 'required|unique:tablename',

this will look for a unique email in a table named tablename.

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice that. Now its working fine